# Is it true that $\forall \epsilon > 0 , a \leq b + \epsilon \Rightarrow a \leq b$?

Tags: inequality

Is it true? I see a lot of inequalities like that in proofs, but i don't understand why it should be true.

Comment: Your question is equivalent at $$\forall \varepsilon>0, a\leq \varepsilon\implies a\leq 0.$$ If $a>0$, take $\varepsilon=\frac{a}{2}$, then $a>\varepsilon$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 9):

If $a\not\le b$, then $a>b$. Let $\epsilon=\frac{a-b}2$: then $\epsilon>0$, and $a=b+2\epsilon>b+\epsilon$, contradicting the hypothesis.